# Is the content of a const std::optional always const?

Tags: c++, c++17

I would assume

```
std::optional<const std::string>
```

allows to assign a new value to the optional, but it is not possible to change the string itself and in

```
const std::optional<const std::string>
```

it is not possible to do both. But what about the following?

```
const std::optional<std::string>
```

Comment: What is the sense to have a optional which is const. As this, there is no option anymore :-)

Comment: If you take a look at the various ways to access the contained value, ([`.value()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/value), [`operator*()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator*)) you will see that the `const`-qualified versions all return a reference to a `const` object.

Comment: @Klaus the option has already been taken. Imagine `f()` returning an optional. There is no reason not to call it with `const auto opt = f();`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let's do some testing then:

```
#include <string>
#include <optional>

int main() {
    using n_c = std::optional<const std::string>;
    using c_n = const std::optional<std::string>;
    using n_n = std::optional<std::string>;

    n_c opt_n_c{"a"};
    c_n opt_c_n{"a"};
    n_n opt_n_n{"a"};

    opt_n_c.emplace("b");
    // opt_c_n.emplace("b");
    opt_n_n.emplace("b");

    // opt_n_c->pop_back();
    // opt_c_n->pop_back();
    opt_n_n->pop_back();
}
```

The commented out lines do not work.

Think of it like this: A non-const `std::optional<T>` can have no value or a `T`, which can be replaced (Not using `T::operator=`, just destructing the currently held `T` if it exists and constructing a new one). A non-const `std::optional<const T>` can do exactly the same, though `const T` probably doesn't have an `operator=`, so you can't mutate the held value, but you can still change what value is held. A `const std::optional<T>` is also "logically const". If a `const std::optional<T>` equals another `const std::optional<T>`, and no non-const references are touched, they (should) always remain equal, so the held value (should) not be changed. This is why they return const-references to the held value, and is why `const std::optional<T>` and `const std::optional<const T>` are effectively the same.

Answer (score 7):

> But what about the following?
>
> ```
> const std::optional<std::string>
> ```

Everything in the standard library is going to be `const`-correct - so the accessors on `optional` are all `const`-qualified as appropriate. Calling [`value()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/value) or [`operator*()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator*) on a `const optional<T>` is going to give you a `const T&` (or `const T&&`), never a `T&`.

You have no direct access to a modifiable reference.

Note that if you had a `const optional<int*>`, on the other hand, it's the pointer itself that is `const` - not the pointee. So this is fine:

```
int i = 42;
const std::optional<int*> opt(&i);
*opt.value() = 57;
assert(i == 57);
```

---

> Is the content of a `const std::optional` always `const`?

Now technically, the above doesn't actually answer your question. A `const std::optional<std::string>` does not hold a `const std::string` - it holds a `std::string` that it only exposes `const` access to. So... technically... but really never do this seriously this is bad... this is well-defined:

```
const std::optional<std::string> opt("hello"s);
const_cast<std::string&>(opt.value()) = "I am a bad person and I feel bad"s;
```

Because the `string` itself was never created as `const`.

Comment: The argument of saying the stardard library is const-correct is somewhat circular, since this question is essentially asking _"what does const-correct mean for `optional<T>`?"_

Comment: @Eric ... which the 2nd sentence answers.